# Is there a way to create a working output stream in the updated Golioth console?

Tags: webhooks, middleware, iot

Golioth updated their website and left out their docs un-updated. I have tried creating a working output stream following the old docs but it is not working. An earlier output stream is working well but I need to add extra output streams. This link provides a procedure-based process of creating an output stream in golioth console, [Golioth Console](https://docs.datacake.de/integrations/golioth). When I follow it, my output is different from what they have. Look at the screenshots below, specifically the "Event Types". This is from the docs, [Old output stream as per the docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sc98t.png) and this one is what I am getting when I try to create a new output stream, [My output stream as per the new updated website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ab1Ca.png). The new one is not able to forward data to Datacake but the old one can. The striking difference between the two is the Event Types. I need help in figuring out how to add the old Event Types in the new output stream.

I've tried creating new projects and adding new output streams like Datacake and webhooks but the result is the same. No data is being forwarded to Datacake platform. I've also tried changing the API keys to no avail. What I am expecting is to see logs at the Datacake platform.